# В чем разница между Class class = new Class() и Class class = new()?

Tags: c#

Такой пример:

```cs
Class class1 = new(); 
Class class2 = new Class();
```

Есть ли разница? Если нет то как правильней писать?

Comment: Нет. Язык развивается, часть рутинных действий упрощают, дублировать постоянно тип напрягало, вот и сделали наконец сокращенный вариант.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разницы нет. `new()` - это нововведение C# 9.

- [Новые возможности C# 9.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#fit-and-finish-features)

Данные записи синтаксически эквивалентны. Разница только в том, что в первом случае слева от равно нельзя использовать ключевое слово `var`, так как оно не определяет тип.

```
var class1 = new(); // ОШИБКА
```

А вот так можно

```
var class2 = new Class();
```

Answer (score 0):

Разницы нету. Просто сокращенный вариант

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).